# Shorter/Better answer to "trim" an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have met a question to trim first 0s and last 0s of an array(all element is 0-9), for example,

- for input `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0]`, the output should be `[1, 0, 2]`
- for input `[1, 0, 2]`, the output should be `[1, 0, 2]`
- for input `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]`, the output should be `[1, 0, 2]`

The basic idea is to find the index of first non-zero number and the last index of non-zero index, and splice the original array.

And my way is to change the array to string and trim it, then change back to array again.
`trimArray=A=>A.join('').replace(/(^['0']*)|(['0']*$)/g, '').split('').map(a=>a-'0')`

Is there any other ideas to do this?

Comment: People, before you try to answer this question, please read it more carefully. There have been _several_ answers so far that did not read the question properly.

Comment: `function() { return [1,0,2]; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do this just using array methods...

```
var a = [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0];
while(a[0] === 0) {
    a.shift();
}

while(a[a.length - 1] === 0) {
    a.pop();
}
console.log(a)
```

If you need to keep the original array intact:(https://jsfiddle.net/4q0un1kp/)

```
function trimZeros(arr)
{
    var result = [...arr];
    while(result[0] === 0) {
        result.shift();
    }

    while(result[result.length - 1] === 0) {
        result.pop();
    }
    return result;
}

var a =  [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0];
var b = trimZeros(a);

alert(a);
alert(b);
```

Comment: Heads up, this both a) Mutates the array, and b) will trim `'0'`s, as well as _any_ falsy value. Consider using the strict equality comparison operator `===`.

Comment: @Oka solid points.. but I feel they might be out of scope for the question. I will however update my answer with a method based approach too.

Comment: @Oka OP already stated that the only possible array values are the numbers 0 through 9. Other "falsey" values are not an issue.

Comment: @Blazemonger It's still important to note your edge cases, considering use cases change.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it super simple, we can increment and decrement borderlines for where a `slice` should take place from and to.

This algorithm is O(n), and has the benefit of minimal function invocations.

```js
function trimZeros (array) {
  var front, back, length = array.length;

  if (!length) return [];

  front = 0;
  back = length - 1;

  while (array[front] === 0) front++

  if (front === length) return [];

  while (array[back] === 0) back--;

  return array.slice(front, back + 1);
}

console.log(trimZeros([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0]))
```

Alternatively, you could compose this as a method which takes a functional test, creating a more generic version. This version has bounds checking (in case of trying to trim `undefined`).

```js
if (!Array.prototype.trim) {
  Array.prototype.trim = function (test) {
    var start, end, length = this.length;

    if (!length) return [];

    start = 0;
    end = length - 1;

    while (start < length && test(this[start], start)) start++;

    if (start === end) return [];

    while (end >= 0 && test(this[end], end)) end--;

    return this.slice(start, end + 1);
  }
}

console.log([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0].trim(e => e === 0));
```

Comment: This is a lot cleaner and faster than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this recursive solution to remove every zero in the beginning or end of an array

```
var array = [0,0,1,2,0,5,0,0,0,0];

// function to remove all zeros
function removeZeros(array){

  if(array[0] === 0 && array[array.length-1] === 0){
    return removeZeros(array.slice(1,array.length-1));
  }
  else if(array[0] === 0){
    array.shift();
    return removeZeros(array);
  }
  else if(array[array.length-1] === 0){
    array.pop();
    return removeZeros(array);
  }
  else{
    return array;
  }
}

console.log(removeZeros(array)); //[1, 2, 0, 5]
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a for loop:

```js
function trimArray(arr) {
  var lastIndex = arr.length - 1;
  var low = {
      found: false,
      index: 0
    },
    high = {
      found: false,
      index: arr.length
    };

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!low.found && arr[i] !== 0) {
      low.index = i;
      low.found = true;
    }
    if (!high.found && arr[lastIndex - i] !== 0) {
      high.index = (lastIndex - i) + 1;
      high.found = true;
    }
    if (high.found && low.found) break;
  }

  if (high.found && low.found) {
    var highCut = -(arr.length - high.index)
    return arr.slice(low.index, highCut ? highCut : arr.length);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

var testCases = [
    [0],
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1]
  ];

var result = testCases.map(trimArray);
results.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, null);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var arr = [0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0];

while (arr[0] === 0) {
    arr.shift();
}
while (arr[arr.length-1] === 0) {
    arr.pop();
}
```

Comment: This will trim only one zero from both ends.

Comment: @Juhana as I know this is what author nids - "to trim first 0s and last 0s of an array"

Comment: No, the "s" in "0s" means plural. "[all] first zeros" and "[all] last zeros". Look at the third example in the question.